# Auto open/close brackets in Geany

Tags: editor, brackets, geany

I started using Geany to programm in PHP. I noticed that, when I'm writting a condition for example (or any type of loop), when I hit the `tab` key right after the `if` or `while` instruction, the code finishes writing itself automatically. But the brackets don't go where I want the to go.

**Here is an example to explain myself :**

So this is the default behavior when I hit the `tab` key :

```
if ()
{

}
```

As you can see, the first bracket goes right underneath the `if` instruction.

But I want it to be like this :

```
if () {

}
```

How could I configure that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this via snippets.conf. Go to Tools->Configuration Files->snippets.conf.
There are plenty possibilities to adjust configuration it's a good point to have a look into [documentation](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#user-definable-snippets).

However, if I understood you correct the snippets should look something like:

```
#....
[PHP]
if=if (%cursor%) {\n %block_cursor% \n\t}
#....
```